# perl how to get full month and date?

Tags: perl, datetime

If today is Jan, 1, 2012, how to return a string of date "20120101' ?

```
sub getDateStr{
    my $date = shift;
    print $date->year.$date->month.$date->day."\n";
    return $date->year.$date->month.$date->day; 
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You've answered your own question.

Comment: If $date is an DateTime object then the code would work. But simpler would be `$date->ymd("")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
use Time::Piece;

$t = localtime()->strftime("%Y%m%d");
```

or simpler

```
$t = localtime()->ymd("");
```

Answer (score 6):

From core Perl:

```
POSIX::strftime( '%Y%m%d', localtime );
```

Comment: The [man page for strftime](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime) documents the meaning of the possible %fields.  Some (such as %F) didn't work on Windows last time I tried but the core ones do.

Answer (score 2):

```
use DateTime;
print DateTime->now->ymd("");
print DateTime->now->strftime("%Y%m%d");
print DateTime->now->format_cldr("yyyyMMdd");
```